# Outputting a column vector $[f(x_1, y_1 ,z_1); f(x_2, y_2, z_2); ... ]$ from an input matrix

Tags: matlab

Okay I'm brand new to MATLAB and my friend asked for help with a homework problem. I came up with an answer just from fiddling with documentation and guess and check, but I was hoping someone could show me a better way.

Here is the setup: you are given a table

```
x   y   z
x_1 y_1 z_1
x_2 y_2 z_2
x_3 y_3 z_3
x_4 y_4 z_4
```

which we have stored in a matrix `M`. We have a function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y-z^3$, not yet defined in MATLAB, and we want to get the column vector

```
[ f(x_1, y_1, z_1)
  f(x_2, y_2, z_2)
  f(x_3, y_3, z_3)
  f(x_4, y_4, z_4) ]
```

The problem states that it must be accomplished in a **single expression**.

The solution I came up with was

```
arrayfun(@(x,y) x^2+y-z^3, M(:,1), M(:,2), M(:,3))
```

As a programmer (not in MATLAB) I say this solution looks like garbage. Is there a better/more accepted way to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function `f(x,y,z)`is fixed, you can just operate on the matrix elements directly, i.e. you could write

```
M(:,1).^2 + M(:,2) - M(:,3).^3
```

to get the required output vector.

Answer (score 0):

And if f is not a fixed function, I would go for something like this

```
g = @(row) f(row(1), row(2), row(3));
arrayfun(@(r) g(M(r,:)), 1:size(M,1));
```